# Rails Application Showing 'index of /cms' instead of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, apache, centos

I'm using CentOS 6 and Apache trying to set up a rails app. I've been having fits with this for a week now.

Here is what I have in my httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost 184.75.252.232:80
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost *:

<VirtualHost 184.75.252.232:80>
ServerName austingatesdesign.us
ServerAlias www.austingatesdesign.us
DocumentRoot /home/portfolio/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@austingatesdesign.us
UseCanonicalName Off
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/austingatesdesign.us combined
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/austingatesdesign.us-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I     .\n%{%s}t %O ."
## User portfolio # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
UserDir enabled portfolio
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup portfolio portfolio
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup portfolio portfolio
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid portfolio portfolio
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID portfolio portfolio
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/portfolio/public_html/cgi-bin/




# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
# Include    "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/portfolio/austingatesdesign.us/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 184.75.252.232:80>
ServerName ausgates.me
ServerAlias www.ausgates.me
DocumentRoot /home/austin/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@ausgates.me
UseCanonicalName Off
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/ausgates.me combined
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/ausgates.me-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
## User austin # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
UserDir enabled austin
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup austin austin
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup austin austin
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid austin austin
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID austin austin
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/austin/public_html/cgi-bin/




# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/austin/ausgates.me/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 184.75.252.232:80>
DocumentRoot /home/austin/public_html/cms/public
ServerName ausgates.me


# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

The app is located at /home/austin/public-html/cms

```
root@server [/home/austin/public_html]# ls
./          cms/            Images/           main.css        watch.html
../         entropybanner/  index.html        normalize.css
404.html    favicon.gif     lightbox.css      photos.html
about.html  favicon.png     lightbox.min.js   responsive.css
cgi-bin/    favicon.svg     lightbox.min.map  script.js
```

And the app itself:

```
root@server [/home/austin/public_html/cms]# ls
./    bin/       db/           .gitignore  public/      test/
../   config/    Gemfile       lib/        Rakefile     tmp/
app/  config.ru  Gemfile.lock  log/        README.rdoc  vendor/
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure it out and every tutorial online is outdated, or has steps that don't all quite fit together. I'm at a loss and I'm sure it's a noobish mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your DocumentRoot in your config points to `/home/portfolio/public_html`, but your app resides in `/home/austin/public_html`

Second: Are you using passenger and are you familiar with it? Maybe this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6) can help you setting up a rails/apache/CentOS environment